# I am voted down without reason

Tags: support, stack-overflow, specific-question, down-votes

I answered the following question

- [Reduce link (URL) size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14135342/reduce-link-url-size#answer-14135484)

The (now deleted) answer was voted down without reason. Could someone suggest what should I do in this case?

Comment: Swallow and move on? I sometimes post a comment on my answer after a downvote along the lines of: "I'd love to know what was not helpful or wrong about my answer to deserve a downvote; feedback will help me improve it!" but that's about all you can do.

Comment: Actually, the person **did** now comment on why they downvoted. What more do you want?

Comment: I quote: *"I voted your post down because it seems you misunderstood the question. The original poster was not looking for a way that solves only his examples, he was looking for an automatic, general way to simplify URLs"*...there you go. Problem solved.

Comment: Someone thought the answer was not optimal for some reason. The occasional down vote is just part of participating, don't take it personally. As the answer is now deleted, I'm closing this out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't do anything.  If others think your answer was good, they will upvote and you'll come out ahead on balance.  People are free to downvote their conscience if they think your answer isn't good.